# Trigger action withing element

Tags: jquery

I wrote a small plug-in to get element and put it into modal box. Once the element is selected it is appended to the body like this:

```
$('body').append(overlay, modal).show();
```

However, I just noticed that I can't seem to be able to detect any action when an element within the modal is clicked or selected.

I tried .on() and .live() to no avail.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myLink').click(function() {
        $('#myEl').myModal();
    });

    $('#myLink').on('click', function() {
        alert('clicked me!');
    });
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#myLink', function() {
        alert('clicked me!');
    });
});
```

Ideally you want to use a selector closer in the DOM to the element than `document`, one that is present when the document is ready. According to the jQuery docs for [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page.